# Generate random number belonging to exponential distribution

Tags: c++, random, logarithm, exponential

I'm trying to generate random values belonging to an exponential distribution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double x;
    double random;
    double one=1.0;
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        x = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
        cout << random <<endl;
        x=log(one-random)/(-3);
        cout<< x<< endl;
        cout<< "__"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using this formula `x = log(1-u)/(−λ)` that I have read in this post [Pseudorandom Number Generator - Exponential Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106503/pseudorandom-number-generator-exponential-distribution)

But the output that I see is this one:

```
3.90272e-319
0
__
3.90272e-319
0
__
3.90272e-319
0
__
3.90272e-319
0
__
and so on
```

It is always printed the same value of the random number and also the result of the logarithm is always 0, I can't understand way.

Comment: You need to call srand with the time or something, to get some different numbers each run.

Comment: change line to `x = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));` to `random = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));`

Comment: The output of `rand()` is never actually used in the example code. It is clobbered a few lines down. Thus the fact that the random seed is not initialized is not where the problem lies, and makes this question not exactly a duplicate of questions relating to the use of `rand()`.

Comment: And you could remove `one-`, U(0,1) is equivalent to 1-U(0,1)

Comment: You wouldn't have needed to write code; C++ has a built-in exponential distribution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491458/how-to-generate-random-numbers-with-exponential-distribution-with-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `random` uninitialized, so it is undefined what value it will hold. And you are never changing its value, so each iteration of the loop it will behave the same.

Comment: oh! I missed it. thks

Comment: @Domenico: Please note that your compiler should have told you "reading from uninitialized variable `random`".  Make sure that your warnings are turned on, and then pay attention to them.